# What is the storage location of an Embedded Derby database created as a GlobalNamingResource in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, derby

Currently I'm using Embedded Derby Database that is created by first use of a GlobalNamingResource specified in tomcat 8.0's server.xml (on Windows 7).

Currently I can use it within the Java code, but if I want to access it with other tools like the Eclipse Data Source Explorer, I can not find it anywhere on my filesystems (in Windows 7).

The concerning part of my server.xml looks like this:

```
<Resource auth="Container"
    driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" 
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
    name="jdbc/myDB" password="" username=""
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:derby:Databases/myDerbyDB;create=true" />
```

The context.xml contains this:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/myDBLink" global="jdbc/myDB" 
    auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

The Java Code uses (a bit shortened):

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) env.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDBLink");
```

This works great accross restarts and reboots of my tomcat server. Database can be accessed using Hibernate, EclipseLink, pure JDBC,... and data is well persisted therein. Documentation states, that is should be stored somewhere below CATALINA_HOME, but there I can not find anything looking like a Derby DB. Also when I search through all my Disks, I can not find a folder named `myDerbyDB` nor a folder `Databases` containing something related.

So my question is: Where Derby is storing my data?

Comment: What tool are you using to search your disks? Given that JDBC Connection URL, you absolutely should be able to find that folder. Perhaps you are running Tomcat on a different server, and you're searching the wrong server? Try searching for a folder named "seg0", or for a file named 'db.lck'. When you say you can access the Database through "pure JDBC", do you mean you are accessing the **same** database? If so, what JDBC Connection URL are you using in that "pure JDBC" program and can you determine where **it** is storing the database?

Comment: Your database will be in `$WORKING_DIR\Databases\myDerbyDB`. If you're running Tomcat as a Windows service then `$WORKING_DIR` will be dependent upon how the Windows Service mechanism sets this. You may have trouble finding it if the service is running as some user identity that is not your normal login.

Comment: Derby is run in embedded mode as a global Resource in tomcat (meaning not global in terms of the system). Tomcat itself is started by Eclipse. I used Windows Explorer to search for the folders named like the Database (e.g. myDerbyDB). Interestingly, when I search for "seg0", I get a result and it points to the eclipse installation path (in my example: D:\jee-neon\eclipse\Databases\<name>\seg0). This did not show up when searching with the Databases' names. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the comments from Bryan and Steve, I found an answer to my own question.

For Tomcat managed Derby Embedded databases, with tomcat running in Eclipse under Windows, the derby.system.home seems to refer to the Eclipse **installation** folder not it's workspace.

So when your Eclipse IDE is installed below

```
D:\eclipse
```

the JDBC URL

```
jdbc:derby:Databases/myDerbyDB
```

will refer to a Derby database located in

```
D:\eclipse\Databases\myDerbyDB
```

Thanks Steve and Bryan!